# Shell: Expand $HOME from regular file

Tags: shell, sh, exec, variable-expansion

I'm storing commands in a file to be read and run line by line by a POSIX shell program. It looks something like this:

```
curl -fLo $HOME/.antigen.zsh git.io/antigen
curl -fLo $HOME/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
vim +"so $HOME/.vimrc" +PlugInstall +qa!
```

I'm also using this small function body to go through it and run every line:

```sh
while read -r line; do
    $line
done < file
```

Simple stuff. And it works! However, I am having trouble expanding `$HOME` to my home directory (and `~` for that matter). I've tried using an `exec` subshell and removing the `-r` from the `read` loop but the `curl` statements create a `'$HOME'` directory, which is not what I want to do, I want the commands to target my `/home/.\+/` directory.

Since this is a strange question and you'll probably be wondering at this point (I certainly would), this is not an XY problem. I have spent a considerable time designing this piece of software and am certain that I **need** to store these commands in a file for my program to work and I won't consider doing otherwise unless this is proven absolutely impossible. Also, I'm not expanding `$HOME` myself because I want the commands to work in other users' computers.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sh -c "$line"`?  Or `eval $line`?  Usually `eval` is regarded as dangerous; I'm not sure that `sh -c` is much different, though.  Come to think of it, why not simply execute the file storing the commands?  `sh "$file"`?  You can use `sh -e "$file"` to stop on an unchecked error, and add `-x` to see what is being executed.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thank you very much @JonathanLeffler. `sh -c "$line"` works flawlessly and solves the problem. Add it as a definitive answer please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

Can you use:

```
sh -c "$line"
```

Or:

```
eval $line
```

Usually `eval` is regarded as dangerous, but I'm not sure that `sh -c` is much different. Come to think of it, why not simply execute the file storing the commands?

```
sh "$file"
```

You can use `sh -e "$file"` to stop on an unchecked error, and add `-x` to see what is being executed.